# Why the java program cannot be connected to Apache IoTDB server when cli tool already been connected?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After docker is started in Apache IoTDB, I can connect IoTDB using cli in the server, but the iava program cannot be connected to the server. What may be the reason for this problem? I also checked that the port I am using has already been mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default monitoring port is 127.0.0.1, so it cannot be used even if you mapped it. You can change `dn_rpc_address` in Apache IoTDB to 0.0.0.0 and try again.